# I cant catch the server respond message for exception 400 - Java API

Tags: java, api

I'm starting scans from my java engine to Rapid7 tool via API.
I want to catch and print the message from the server when the respond is 400.
Server returns JSON

```
 {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "An unexpected error occurred. See the log file for more information or contact support.",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "api/3/sites/3/scans",
            "rel": "self"
        }
    ]
 }
```

I want to print this message to the console.
starting scan and reading respond back works fine (server respond https 200,201).
the issue is server respond 400.

code for reading server respond

```
httpsCode = connection.getResponseCode();

while (true)
                    {
                        //Read
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
// jumps from here to Catch when https code = 400

                        String lines = null;                         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            stringBuilder.append(lines);
                        }
                        bufferedReader.close();
                        result = stringBuilder.toString();

                        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                        JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);

                        if(httpsCode ==200 || httpsCode ==201)
                        {
                            if(methodType == MethodType.Add_host_To_Site && method.equals("POST"))
                            {
                                System.out.print("\n Rapid7 : Successful POST, host was added to Rapid7, " + splunkdata.getHost_fqdn() );
                                String asset_id= json2.get("id").toString();
                                splunkdata.getScan().setAsset_Id(Integer.parseInt(asset_id));
                                System.out.print("\n Rapid7 : Asset_id is set successfully , " + splunkdata.getHost_fqdn() );
                            } 
}

 if (httpsCode == 400 || httpsCode == 401)
                        {
                            System.out.print(" Rapid7 : Rapid7 InsightVM throws Exception, \n Message : " + json2.get("message")  );
                        }

 connection.disconnect();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { // jump to IOException
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

what could be causing this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Where is httpsCode getting its value from? I don't see any catch either -- why would it jump to your httpsCode checks from where you wrote that comment? Does the server return the HTTP code 400, too, or is it just a status code insider the returned content body?

Comment: I have edited the code, forgot to include that part. thanks

Comment: It looks like this is the intended behavior. You can try calling `getErrorStream` for a 400 response status. That will give you an `InputStream` as well, but with the error response. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream--)

Comment: I have tried it to read the server respond using geterrorstream but still it jumps from to catch exception. any other suggestion ?